# Repeatedly execute an SQL query for column data

Tags: sql-server

I have a table (Personel) that has the usual person info in it.

I have a sporting stats query that lists all the games a person has played.

How can I generate a result for each person separately (as in, if you run two select statements, you get two lots of results returned).

I don't want all the results in one table (and I'd prefer to avoid cursors).

(Using SQL Server 2022).

Comment: *"(Using SQL Server 2018)."* Impossible, there is no SQL Server 2018; there were releases in 2017 and 2019 but there wasn't one in 2018. The most "recent" releases (and their version) of SQL Server are: 2008 (10), 2008R2 (10.5), 2012 (11), 2014 (12), 2016 (13), 2017 (14), 2019 (15), and 2022 (16). Which are you *actually* using?

Comment: Create a cursor that loops every person in the table and executes your query

Comment: This is not clear at all. Why do you want a separate result set for each person?

Comment: @SeanLange I want to list all the games each person has played.  I'd like those results separate.

Comment: If you want multiple result sets then you will need to execute each query one at a time. A cursor is the answer to that. But I would think that you can find a better solution to whatever it is you are trying to do than separate result sets. This sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.